# For an array A [0...N-1] how many times must I decrement elements before no two non-zero elements will have difference > M?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

An array of size N  A [0...N-1] contains some positive integers. What is the minimum number of times that I need to decrement some element so that no two elements (A[i] and A[j] , i != j, A[i]>0, A[j]>0) have difference > M ?

My approach so far :

```
for(int i = N-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    for(int j = 0;j<=i-1;j++)
    {
        while(A[i]-A[j]>M)
        {
            A[i]--;
            ans++;
        }

    }

}
```

But,this is not the correct solution.
For example,

A = {3 2 1} and M = 0

The optimal solution is decrementing A[2] by once and A[0] by once.

That makes the array A = {2 2 0}

As, A[2] = 0 we can ignore it as we only worry about non zero element.

But,this code produces ans = 3.

What is a solution to do it ?

Comment: Your language is inconsistent. "Removing" an element is not the same as "decreasing" an element.

Comment: Your title says exactly the opposite of what you do. Please double check < vs >

Comment: Yeah , I corrected it in the body . Sorry for the confusion

Comment: No,if A = {1 2 3} .  Then , I can do the following steps to make everything 2. Make A[0] - 1 = 0 . Now , as It is 0 we can assume it is not in the list anymore . Then , I can make A[2] -1 = 2 . Now A contains {2 2} . So, in 2 steps I have made differences 0 .

Comment: Are the arrays sorted?   Are the values unique or duplicated?    Are you referring to actual difference between elements, or magnitude of difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in the end, after all decreases are done, the list will contain these kinds of elements:

- 0-valued elements, which need not to be taken into account (they are removed)
- a minimum value `min` (which may occur one or multiple times)
- elements in between `min` and `min + M`.

---

**If the final minimum value (`min`) would be known in advance**, the following procedure could be applied:

- decrease all elements larger than `min + M` until they are equal to `min + M`.
- decrease all elements smaller than `min` until they become 0 (*i.e.* eliminate them).

---

Now, the problem is that we don't know in advance what will be the minimum value in the end.

However, a **key observation** is that the final minimum value (`min`) will for sure be one of the initial values in the input list (otherwise we would get a sub-optimal solution).

Thus, to solve this task, you can take each value in the input list as a candidate for the final minimum value (`min`), apply for each the procedure described above, and, finally, select the best of the solutions generated in this way.

---

**Example**. For the {1, 2, 3} input list and M = 0.

Each number in the input set will be a candidate for `min`.

- `min = 1`. Then we need to decrement A[2] once, and A[3] twice (**3 operations**). The resulting set is {1, 1, 1}.
- `min = 2`. We need to decrement A[1], in order to eliminate it, and A[3] once in order to make it inside the allowed range (**2 operations**). The resulting set is {2, 2}.
- `min = 3`. We need to eliminate A[1] by decrementing it once and A[2], by decrementing it twice (**3 operations**). The resulting set is {3}.

The best alternative among the ones above is to make `min = 2` (which required 2 decrement operations). The resulting set is **{2, 2}**.

Comment: Making it a bit more concrete, the quantity to be minimized is `sum [ x for x in A if x < min ] + sum [ x - (min + M) for x in A if x > min + M ]`, with respect to `min`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in O(N log N) time, or O(N) time if the array is presorted.

In pseudo-code:

```
Given:  A : array of ints, M = max difference

sort(A); //O(N log N) time

int start = end = 0;  //this is a subsequence that we will move though the array

int sum_before = 0; //sum of all elements before our subsequence
int sum_after = sum_all(A); // sum of all elements after our subsequence -- O(N) time

int best_answer = sum_after; //we could always decrement everything to zero

for (start=0; start < A.length; ++start )
{
   int maxval = A[start]+M;  //A is sorted, so this never gets smaller

   //extend end to find the longest subsequence starting
   //at A[start] that we don't have to change

   while( end < A.length && A[end]<=maxval)
   {
       //we can increment end at most A.length times, so
       //this loop is O(N) in total for all iterations

       sum_after-=A[end];
       ++end;
   }

   //if we leave everything between start and end unchanged
   //the we'll need to decrement everything before to zero and
   //everything after to maxval

   int current_answer = sum_before + sum_after - (A.length - end)*maxval;

   best_answer = min(best_answer, current_answer);

   //next subsequence excludes A[start] -- it goes into the "before" sum
   sum_before+=A[start];
}
```